# Find the complexity of a for loop over a set of matrices

Tags: algorithm, combinations, complexity-theory

As I'm modeling an interactive network in R, I'm facing the following problem:

**S** is the set of all (n x n) square matrices like **A** such that:

- All the values on the main diagonal of **A** are 0.
- All the other values (i.e. **Aij**s such that **i** is not equal to **j**) are either 0 or 1.
- If **Aij** = 1 then **Aji** = 0. (but, if **Aij** = 0, **Aji** may or may not be 0)

What is the cardinal of **S**?

I'm going to write a program that loops over all of such matrices (all members of **S**) to check some properties. I know that the complexity is exponential, however, I want to check it only for some small networks. So, I want to have an understanding of the growth of the cardinal of **S** as n increases for some *small* numbers. Ideally, I am looking for a function that gets n and returns the cardinal of **S**. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cardinality of S is `3^(N(N-1)/2)` since each pair can have three states (`00`,`01`,`10`), and the number of pairs is the number of entries in the matrix `(NxN)`, minus the number of entries on the diagonal `(N)`, divided by `2` (2 entries per pair).